# MySQL - How to create a new table that is a join on primary key of two existing tables

Tags: mysql, join, merge, create-table

I have two existing tables, with different fields, except for Primary ID (a `varchar`, not an `int`). I want to create a third table which is essentially a merge of these two, such that for a given Primary Key I have all fields in one table.

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you sure you want a table (that contains a snapshot of current data in your tables and will not reflect future changes)? Aren't you looking for a view (which always looks at the current data in tables)?

Comment: Hi Bandi-T - that's a good thought, and in fact thinking about it maybe i don't need to merge them. However, the data is reasonably static, will only be updated in batch every month or so.

Comment: well, if you choose a table, the DBMS only calculates once and does not follow changes in source data. If you choose a view, the DBMS calculates every time someone queries that view, but it will always contain fresh data.

If you have to perform many queries on this merged data (I guess you will query more often than the updates happen), then it may very well be worth choosing to use a table.

Comment: @Bandi-T - yeah it will be queried much more frequently than updated. However the data sets are largish, so might save myself some pain and go with the view model anyway

Comment: Yes, I'd feel better with that - see TMN's answer below.

Of course the width and height of the tables also factors into this, as well as what kind of queries you will have. And then we didn't even start considering adding indexes to speed up queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you have one and exactly one row in both tables for a given primary ID, then this should work:

```
SELECT
    tablea.field1, tablea.field2, tablea.field3, ... tablea.fieldn, <---- field list
    tableb.field1, tableb.field2, tableb.field3, ... tableb.fieldm  <---- field list
FROM
    tablea, tableb
WHERE
    tablea.primaryID = tableb.primaryID
```

You might want to omit tablea's and tableb's primary ID field from the field list if you do not actually need them (in this query both will contain the same value due to the `tablea.primaryID = tableb.primaryID` condition).

The syntax is relatively similar for a `VIEW` as well.

Comment: Yes fairly sure that there's only one row for a given PID in each table. The PID is set as PRIMARY KEY - presumably MySQL would barf on import if there was dupe?

Comment: @Richard: Yes, it would. However, for the above query to give all your rows exactly once, you also have to make sure the rows (records) can be matched exactly 1:1 to each other in the two tables. If you have a primary key of say 3 in one table, but there is no primary key 3 in the other table, there will be no row with that `3` in the result, because there is no matching `3` row in the other table.

Answer (score 37):

```
CREATE TABLE result AS 
  (SELECT first.*, 
          second.f1, 
          second.f2, 
          second.f3 
   FROM   first 
          INNER JOIN second 
                  ON first.id = second.id);
```

To get a view, do the same except replace "TABLE" with "VIEW". If you go with the table rather than the view, make sure to add a primary key as that will not be added by default.

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL use this

```
SELECT * INTO result 
FROM  table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score -4):

Why are you creating a new table?  Why don't you just execute a query whenever you need the data?  If you're just joining two tables on their primary key, then the majority of your data access time is going to be spent marshalling the data back to your application. You're not going to be saving much time pre-joining the tables, and you'll be eating a lot of space.  Plus, you're taking aim at your big toe, just waiting for the first time you update your source tables and forget to run your update script to copy the changes to your joined table.  Duplicate data is *evil*, but sometimes it's necessary.  This doesn't sound like one of those times.