# How to build a new MySQL Table from 2 MySQL Tables without PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables I want to merge into a third table I would like to do it purely as a MySQL query rather than selecting the rows and using PHP while() to build the third table.

Table 1 contains the following

```
ID Name
1  A
2
3
```

Table 2 contains the following

```
ID  Desc
10
15  B
20
```

I want to write a query statement to produce the following combined table, but I only want the new Desc to contain the non-blank value from Name in Table 1 or Desc in Table 2, with Table 2 getting precedence over Table 1 in the event both tables contain a non-blank

```
ID1 ID2 Desc
1   10  A
1   15  B
1   20  A
2   10
2   15  B
2   20
3   10
3   15  B
3   20
```

Is this do-able as a MySQL query I should I use a PHP method?

Thanks.

Comment: That's basically the same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112043/mysql-how-to-create-a-new-table-that-is-a-join-on-primary-key-of-two-existing

Comment: Most data-related procedures are doable in pure SQL... See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html) for your answer.

Comment: Well, maybe @LawsonCulver. However I do not want to "create" a new table per se...I want to refresh an already existing table by resetting it to the data in Table 1 and Table 2. Would it be an "UPDATE TABLE result AS..." instead?

Comment: If you're "resetting" the data, you might as well get rid of the rows first, then use an INSERT (as long as there is nothing that needs to remain there.)  If you don't want to lose other stuff in there, it gets more complicated.  You'd have to UPDATE when it exists, and INSERT when it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into TableThree (id1, id2, Descr)
select
    T1.id,
    T2.id,
    case LENGTH(TRIM(T2.Descr))
        when 0 then T1.Name
        else T2.Descr
    end
from TableOne T1, TableTwo T2
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: nice @ChrisPiazza .. looks like something I can work with. I'll post back on my results and accept your solution as the answer once I get it working. Greatly appreciate your help...

Comment: You're a star @ChrisPiazza! That worked perfectly. Greatly, greatly appreciate the help (and the learning).

Answer (score 0):

Think, you need this one...

```
select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, if(length(t2.name), t2.desc, t1.name) as desc from t1,t2;
```

Comment: I was thinking the solution needed to be a bit more robust than this because it needs to contain the "INSERT INTO" in order to get the new table to build (at least I think so). @v.sheldeshov

Comment: it **is** robust. just try to break it! )) .... also it works on ancient sql engines like mysql 3

Comment: Well, my problem is I am just not seeing how the selected data gets inserted in Table 3 @v.sheldeshov

Comment: You can insert with "insert into select" syntax. http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-insert-into-select.html

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

SELECT a.ID as ID1, b.ID as ID2, (CASE WHEN b.Desc is not null THEN b.Desc ELSE a.Name END) as Desc from Table1 a full join Table2;

But this is untested ... so good luck.

Regards

parascus

Comment: I was thinking the solution needed to be a bit more robust than this because it needs to contain the "INSERT INTO" in order to get the new table to build (at least I think so). @parascus

Comment: You can create the new Table by "create table x as SELECT ..." only if the table already exists you have to use "INSERT INTO".